# Append Html link with ImageIcon on JTextPane?

Tags: java, html, swing, user-interface, jtextpane

I m trying to load Image icon on JTextPane with HtmlLink but the HtmlLink get displayed on next line of icon like this....

```
          ImageICON
          HTMLLINK
```

I m  Expecting output: ICON  HTMLDATA

```
       jTextPane2.insertIcon(icon);
        kit.insertHTML(hdoc,hdoc.getLength(),string_html, 0, 0,null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the string_html content. It must not have any block tags like < html >, < p >, < br >, < body > etc.

Comment: no it's just       string_html="<a href=\""+path+"\">" +name+"</a>" ;

Comment: Also you can use HTMLDocument's methods, insertHTMLBeforeStart, insertHTMLAfterStart, insertHTMLBeforeEnd, insertHTMLAfterEnd